# How to send form input values from HTML to application's logic?

Tags: php, forms

I have my own  project and I don't know how to send form input values from HTML form to (what I call) loginController. Have you got any tips for me ?
[PHOTO OF A CONSTRUCTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRrbX.png)

Comment: Who upvoted this question??

Comment: That's not a view, but just a HTML template. And you send the data by submitting the for. And this has nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: Add the url of the file in form `action` attribute and access the data in the php file using `$_POST` if form is a post request, or $_GET if is a get request.